# How to tear down Core Data Stack?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, xctest

I want to add unit tests for my Core Data app, but I am sure how to reset the context between tests.

This is my `CoreDataStack` object:

```
public final class CoreDataStack {
    var storeType: StoreType!
    public init(storeType: StoreType) {
        self.storeType = storeType
    }

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Transaction")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                description.type = self.storeType.type

            }
        })

        return container
    }()

    public var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using it in my tests:

```
class PaymentTests: XCTestCase {

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack(storeType: .inMemory)
        context = coreDataStack.context
    }
}
```

I tried to call `context.reset()` inside `tearDown` function but, the data is not reset, it's always persistent.

So how can I tear down the Core Data Stack ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The old data has nothing to do with your context but with your `PersistentStore`. This is what you are using Core Data for, persist your data.

Delete the store to get rid of your data before initializing your stack in `setup()`. You can find it like this:

```
let storeUrl = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first!.url!
```

and remove it like this:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
fileManager.removeItem(at: storeUrl)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since 2015, Apple introduced a new method called `destroyPersistentStore(at:,ofType:,options:)`

```
guard let storeURL = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first?.url else {
        return
    }
    do {
        try self.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: storeURL, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

The new way should look like this.

Comment: but how to re-setup this stack then?